# Lambda Calculus (λa.b)((λx.xx)(λx.xx))

Tags: haskell, lambda, functional-programming, lambda-calculus

Im looking for an example of a weakly normalising lambda term.
Am I right in saying that the following:

```
(λa.b)((λx.xx)(λx.xx))
```

Reduces to:

```
b
```

or:

doesnt terminate (if you try to reduce `(λx.xx)(λx.xx)`)

I wasnt sure if the first reduction is correct so just need some clarification,
thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about CS theory: cstheory.stackexchange.com would be better.

Comment: The answer should be "b". Because for any a (\a.b) reduces b, we even don't need to evaluate a.

Comment: great, thanks. thought that was right just wasnt sure of my answer ^^

Answer (score 8):

If you evaluate the right term first and continually then it will never reach a normal form, thus it is not strongly normalizable. If you evaluate the left term first it will immediately reach a normal form, thus it is normalizable and demonstrates that this term is weakly normalizable. It's also an example of the non-confluence of the untyped lambda calculus.

Note that you're more likely to want to talk about how a rewriting system is normalizing than a particular term. This term is thus a counterexample to the strong normalization property of untyped lambda calculus, but does not provide positive evidence that ULC is weakly normalizing (and it isn't).